# Getting onto a specific user's profile through clicking on username's link in Grails

Tags: grails, user-profile

I ma using grails 2.1.1 and developing a twitter clone application. When a user has posted a post, my application shows a list of those posts with the user's photo, his/her Full Name and username, created post and time the post was created. When I click on the username of the user who created the post (which is actually a g:link), I need to get redirected to that specific user's profile, not the active user's profile. Below is my **postentries.gsp** code which shows all the posts of those users whom current active user is following...

```
<div class="container well span8">

    <div class="postImage">
<div class="span1">
        <g:if test="${post.user.profile.photo}">
            <img src="${createLink(controller: 'image', action: 'renderImage', id: post.user.username)}" class="img-rounded"/>
        </g:if>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="postEntry">
        <div class="postText">
                <div class="span8">

            **<g:link controller="post" action="profile"><b>${post.user.profile.fullName}</b>@(${post.user.username})</g:link>**
            ${post.content}

        </div>
        <div class="postDate">
            <h:dateFromNow date="${post.createdOn}"/>
        </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is **profile.gsp** code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="bootstrap"/>
  <title>${user.profile.fullName}'s Profile Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container well span4" id="sidebar">

   </div>

<div class="container well span8">
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid well text-center span6">
    <div class="row-fluid span1">
            <g:if test="${user.profile.photo}">
                <img src="${createLink(controller: 'image', action: 'renderImage', id: user.username)}" class="img-rounded"/>
            </g:if>
    </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
        <h3>${user.profile.fullName}</h3>
        <h4>@${user.username}</h4>
        <h5>${user.profile.country}</h5>
    </div>
        <div class="span3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I click on the username's g:link, I always redirected to active user's profile which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the `id` of the profile you want in your postentries.gsp

```
**<g:link controller="post" action="profile" id="${post?.user?.profile.id}">
   <b>${post.user.profile.fullName}</b>@(${post.user.username})</g:link>**
```